# update python 2.7 to 3.8 on AWS Lambda with AMI Backup script

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

When I update the python 2.7 version to python 3.8, my AMI script is not working properly, after test the code on aws console under the lambda section shows versions mismatch between 2.7 version & 3.8 version. Anybody can help me solve this issue?

Thanks

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import time
import sys

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
sts = boto3.client('sts')
drec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
dr = boto3.resource('ec2')
awsaccountid = sts.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
images = dr.images.filter(Owners=[awsaccountid])
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date_fmt = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
time_fmt = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    def get_instance_name(itags):
        instancename = ''
        if itags is None:
            instancename = ''
        else:
            for tags in itags:
                if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                    instancename = tags["Value"]
        return instancename

    # Check for the availability of the image
    def is_image_available(image_id):
        try:
            available = 0
            while available == 0:
                print("Not created yet.. Gonna sleep for 10 seconds")
                time.sleep(10)
                image = ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])
                if image['Images'][0]['State'] == 'available':
                    available = 1
            if available == 1:
                print("Image is now available for use.")
            return True
        except Exception,e:
            print e

    reservations = ec2.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag:Backup', 'Values': ['yes', 'Yes']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
            ], [])

    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = 2
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7
        finally:
            for image in images:
                #today_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                #today_fmt = today_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                #today_date = time.strptime(today_time, '%m-%d-%Y')
                aminame = get_instance_name(instance['Tags']) + "-" + instance['InstanceId'] + "-On-" + date_fmt
                if image.name == aminame:
                    if is_image_available(image.id):
                        dramiid = drec2.copy_image(SourceRegion='us-east-1', SourceImageId=image.id,
                                                          Name="DR-" + get_instance_name(instance['Tags']) + "-" +
                                                       `enter code here`        instance[
                                                                   'InstanceId'] + "-On-" + date_fmt,
                                                          Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance[
                                                              'InstanceId'] + " On " + time_fmt)
                        print("Retaining DR AMI %s of instance %s for %d days" % (
                            dramiid['ImageId'],
                            instance['InstanceId'],
                            retention_days,
                        ))
                        # to_tag[retention_days].append(dramiid['ImageId'])
                        # for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
                        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
                        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                        print("Will delete the DR AMI in %d days on %s" % (retention_days, delete_fmt))
                        # break
                        drec2.create_tags(
                            Resources=[dramiid['ImageId']],
                            Tags=[
                                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                            ]
                     )
```

It is giving the following error:

```
Function Logs:

START 
RequestId: 1f9263c7-9736-4b31-934d-719d38f8fdba 
Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 52) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/lambda_function.py"
Line 52 except Exception,e:END 
RequestId: 1f9263c7-9736-4b31-934d-719d38f8fdba
```

Do anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: lot of issues, do you have the full script

Comment: Yes This is the full script exept comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do some syntax changes when you are running your script in python3.

For e.g

```
in python 3 , you say `print('value')` with brackets. 
in python 2, you say `print "hello"`

in python 3, you say `except Exception as e`
in python 2, you can say `except Exception, e`
```

here:

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import time
import sys

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
sts = boto3.client('sts')
drec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
dr = boto3.resource('ec2')
awsaccountid = sts.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
images = dr.images.filter(Owners=[awsaccountid])
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date_fmt = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
time_fmt = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    def get_instance_name(itags):
        instancename = ''
        if itags is None:
            instancename = ''
        else:
            for tags in itags:
                if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                    instancename = tags["Value"]
        return instancename

    # Check for the availability of the image
    def is_image_available(image_id):
        try:
            available = 0
            while available == 0:
                print("Not created yet.. Gonna sleep for 10 seconds")
                time.sleep(10)
                image = ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])
                if image['Images'][0]['State'] == 'available':
                    available = 1
            if available == 1:
                print("Image is now available for use.")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    reservations = ec2.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag:Backup', 'Values': ['yes', 'Yes']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
            ], [])

    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = 2
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7
        finally:
            for image in images:
                #today_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                #today_fmt = today_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                #today_date = time.strptime(today_time, '%m-%d-%Y')
                aminame = get_instance_name(instance['Tags']) + "-" + instance['InstanceId'] + "-On-" + date_fmt
                if image.name == aminame:
                    if is_image_available(image.id):
                        dramiid = drec2.copy_image(SourceRegion='us-east-1', SourceImageId=image.id,
                                                          Name="DR-" + get_instance_name(instance['Tags']) + "-" +
                                                       'enter code here' + instance[
                                                                   'InstanceId'] + "-On-" + date_fmt,
                                                          Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance[
                                                              'InstanceId'] + " On " + time_fmt)
                        print("Retaining DR AMI %s of instance %s for %d days" % (
                            dramiid['ImageId'],
                            instance['InstanceId'],
                            retention_days,
                        ))
                        # to_tag[retention_days].append(dramiid['ImageId'])
                        # for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
                        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
                        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
                        print("Will delete the DR AMI in %d days on %s" % (retention_days, delete_fmt))
                        # break
                        drec2.create_tags(
                            Resources=[dramiid['ImageId']],
                            Tags=[
                                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                            ]
                     )
```